# In this AWS CLI command, why copying files with --exclude & --include wildcards not working?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-s3, aws-cli

In the following directory, I want to upload only the `.html` files in top `/DirA/` to the root of my AWS bucket:

**/DirA/**, e.g.

```
.file
fileA.html
fileB.html
fileC.bin
/subdirA
/subdirB
```

When I run the this:

```
me@me:/DirA$ aws s3 cp ./ s3://MYBUCKET/ --dryrun --exclude "*" --include "*.html"
```

The `.html` files are not handled by aws and I just get the empty prompt `me@me:/DirA$` back. No error or the usual `(dry run) upload:` message.

I have also tried

```
me@me:/$ aws s3 cp /DirA/ s3://MYBUCKET/ --dryrun --exclude "*" --include "*.html"
```

with the same empty prompt.

Please note (if helpful):

1. The above were in Ubuntu 18.04 with latest installed AWS CLI v1.
2. I also installed AWS CLI in Windows and did the same, with similar empty result.
3. Uploading stuff which does not require `--exclude` or `--include` like that works normally

What am I doing wrong and how to fix that. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[josedasilva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/264812/josedasilva) is right, you need to use the `--recursive` flag.
Now, to only include only the current directory files, you need to mix some include and exclude flags.

This should do the job:

```
aws s3 cp --recursive ./ s3://MYBUCKET/ --exclude "*" --include "*.html" --exclude "*/*"
```

Answer (score 1):

I do believe you are missing the --recursive option on your command.

Inside your folder:

aws s3 cp . s3://DESTINATION_BUCKET/ --dryrun --exclude="*" --include="*.html" **--recursive**

I found nothing that sustains this need on the doc, although local tests show that only works with this parameter.

Here's the link for the doc on AWS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters

Comment: Your command uploads *all* the files in all dirs including top and within, not what I'm looking for, thanks.